# Use data.com to cleanse/update the data uploaded via csv

Tags: contact, data-loader, data.com

If I am uploading a bunch of contacts (lets say 500 contacts) using the data loader, is it possible to update (cleanse) this data automatically using Data.com?

If it is possible, how would I go about doing this?

Anup

Comment: This really depends on the cleansing being done. Personally, I will always clean the data externally before inserting, usually because it is much easier to script the cleaning with python or PHP. Generally I'll take the original data as a CSV and process it with some scripts to get it into the format I want and then load that santised data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just on a call with Data.com and there is an add-on option to clean your data automatically. It sounds like there is a batch process once a day that compares all the contacts in your org, updates fields that are blank and if also flags the record as being different or in-sync with Data.com. There is no way to only have a subset of the data automatically cleaned. I'd recommend contacting Sales for more information on this feature.